# CSS: Inline-Block and &shy; - Text starts on a new line

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML-code:

```html
<div style="width: 180px;">
  <span>1️</span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
  Lorem ip&shy;sum do&shy;lor sit amet
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem: CSS doesn't treat `&shy;` like a normal linebreak, and therefore the whole text goes in it's own line, instead of "Lorem ipsum do-" being in line with the "1️".

This is what i want it to look like:

```html
<div style="width: 180px;">
<span>1️</span>
<span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
Lorem ipsum do-<br>lor sit amet
</span>
</div>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 180px;">
  <span>1️</span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
  Lorem ip&shy;sum do-
  </span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
  lor sit amet
  </span>
</div>
```

You can try this

Comment: Nope, in your solution the "lor" is below the 1️, but i want it to be right of the 1️ . See my second example, that's EXACTLY what it should look like.

And I don't want any <br> or <span> in the text itself, just &shy; . But i don't know how to make CSS automatically split the text at &shy;, instead of putting it all in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself - simply use **`display: flex;`** on the parent.

```html
<div style="width: 140px; display: flex;">
  <span>1️</span>
  <span>
  Lorem ip&shy;sum do&shy;lor sit amet
  </span>
</div>
```